# Error Connecting to a Win Serv 19 CIFS Share

Tags: 16.04, cifs, smb

I recently decided to upgrade my main file server from Windows Server 2016 to 2019. The issue I'm running into in testing is that my Ubuntu Server 16.04 VMs cannot connect to the Windows CIFS share. I can't seem to find anything about Windows Server 2019 removing SMB features so I'm not sure why this isn't work. The error I get when trying to mount the share is 'Host Down' but I can ping the Windows server just fine from the affected machines. Any ideas? Something in Ubuntu I need to update maybe?

Answer (score 0):

From [this thread.](https://serverfault.com/questions/414074/mount-cifs-host-is-down)

In 2017 Microsoft patched Windows Servers and advised to disable the SMB1 protocol.

From now on, mount.cifs might have problems with the protocol negotiation.

There are 14 responses for you to choose from.